# Output pipe waits for EOF in fish

Tags: grep, pipe, fish

I'd like to take the csearch output and color it. It looks like so:

```
/home/bp/whatever.txt:1:foo
```

And this works:

```
csearch -n -- $term \
  | env GREP_COLORS='mt=02;35' grep --color=always -P '^[^:]+:[^:]+:' \
  | grep -P --color=always -- $term \
  | less -RFX
```

However, it waits for the full output of `csearch` to be computed before anything is shown.

Now, if I do this:

```
csearch -n -- $term \
  | env GREP_COLORS='mt=02;35' grep --color=always -P '^[^:]+:[^:]+:' \
  | pv
  | grep -P --color=always -- $term \
  | less -RFX
```

...I can see the data flowing, but if I do this:

```
csearch -n -- $term \
  | env GREP_COLORS='mt=02;35' grep --color=always -P '^[^:]+:[^:]+:' \
  | grep -P --color=always -- $term \
  | pv
  | less -RFX
```

...no data is flowing. The second `grep` seems to be waiting for an EOF.

Adding `--line-buffered` to both grep's seems to be doing me no good.

Why is this command pipe waiting for EOF?

Comment: …do you think mistaking an executable for a glorified builtin is a typo, or a sporadic issue that went on its own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was using `fish`, which means I wasn't actually using `grep`, but:

```
function grep
    command grep --color=auto $argv
end
```

[and fish code blocks do not stream their output](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/563).

This wasn't a problem in the first `grep` since it was already wrapped by `env`, so it ignored this function.

Changing `grep` to `/bin/grep` fixed it.

Comment: This is fish issue [#2007](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2007).

Comment: @faho or rather #1396 :)